# fsockopen() not working

Tags: php, linux

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 server with Plesk 12, Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.10.
I want to enable reCaptcha for my phpBB board, but every time I get this error: `Could not open socket`

I've enabled `allow_url_fopen` for this domain and temporarily allowed outgoing traffic on port 80 and 443 for all IPs.
According to phpinfo() `allow_url_fopen` is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055472/recaptcha-could-not-open-socket), a similar problem was fixed by changing:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "www.google.com");
```

to:

```
define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", gethostbyname("www.google.com"));
```